# When do we have equality in the third axiom of valuations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, valuation-theory

Let $R$ be a ring and $v: R \to \mathbb Z \cup \{+\infty\}$ a map that meets following axioms:

1. $v(a) = +\infty \iff a=0$
2. $v(ab) = v(a)+v(b)$
3. $v(a+b) \geq \min\{v(a),v(b)\}$

I have to show that $v(a) \neq v(b)$ implies $v(a+b) = \min\{v(a),v(b)\}$, but I have no idea where to begin, can anyone give me some hints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume $v(a)>v(b)$ and $v(a+b)>v(b)$. 
Then 
$$ v(b)=v((a+b)+(-a))\ge\min\{v(a+b),v(-a)\}=\min\{v(a+b),v(a)\}>v(b).$$

Comment: You should also prove that $v(-a)=v(a)$, but it's easy.

Comment: @egreg This would just have been my follow up question, I tried to prove this but I just do not get anywhere, can you give me another hint how to prove $v(-a) = v(a)$?

Comment: @hagenvoneitzen Thank you very much for your elegant answer so far!

Comment: @flawr Prove $v(1)=0$, then $v(-1)=0$ follows; therefore $v(-a)=v((-1)a)=v(-1)+v(a)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems so easy when you know the solution, but it seems you just have to *see it* or you'll never *see it* =)